# Angular 8: Using two external angular packages in same component - moment.js

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I **need** to use the external package [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) (to log the normal, current date) and another external package [moment-feiertage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-feiertage) (for german public holidays).

My problem is, that `Moment.js` and `moment-feiertage` are both using `moment` for their functionality.

How am i able to use `import * as moment from 'moment';` and `import * as moment from 'moment-feiertage';` in the same component, at the same time?

My `examples.component.ts` is containing following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
//import * as moment from 'moment-feiertage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  public today: string;
  public todayIsHoliday: boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.today = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    console.log('today: ', this.today);

    //this.todayIsHoliday = moment().isHoliday();
    //console.log('todayIsHoliday: ', this.todayIsHoliday);
  }
}
```

Comment: you can't use the same name twice, that's pretty much the reason for aliasing. why don't you simply use a different alias for feiertage? and most probably you only need to import the second one anyway.

Comment: from the docs: moment-feiertage exports the original moment object with extended functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the very first section in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-feiertage#how-to-use) explains, moment-feiertage exports the original moment object with extended functionality, so you simply `import * as moment from 'moment-feiertage` and use that instead of the original moment.